# Selling a child-theme of twenty-thirteen is legal?

Tags: child-theme

I built a child-theme based on twenty-thirteen theme, the basic ones that comes bulit-in wordpress.
Can I sell it now on [codecanyon](http://codecanyon.net/)

and make a profit from the child-theme i built and developed? is it legal?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Programmers.SE is a site where legal questions are on-topic. Please read a sites [faq] to see what's on topic before asking. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, however the license on it must be GPL, as the original theme is GPL and the child theme is a derivative work from it. Therefore the GPL's derivative work clause applies, and the license for the child must be GPL.

But yes, the GPL does not prohibit selling a work, as long as you abide by the terms of the license.

Reference:
https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#DoesTheGPLAllowMoney

> **Does the GPL allow me to sell copies of the program for money?**
>
> Yes, the GPL allows everyone to do this. The
>   right to sell copies is part of the definition of free software.
>   Except in one special situation, there is no limit on what price you
>   can charge. (The one exception is the required written offer to
>   provide source code that must accompany binary-only release.)

Comment: Umm, the license of Twenty-Thirteen is:
"License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html",
So does that mean I can sell my child-theme based on twenty-thirteen, and make a profit out of it?
And do I have to make my child-theme the same license too?

Comment: Umm, what do you think "GPL" is an acronym for? Duh.

Comment: *recursive acronym, to be exact.

Comment: So that means i can freely sell my child-theme based on twenty-thirteen as long as it is based on the same license?

Comment: @Roni: The answer is yes, as I actually stated in the answer above. Is the answer unclear somehow? You're asking the same question repeatedly here, and the answer is very clearly and very obviously YES.